# emacs tramp configure prefix macs os x

Tags: emacs, configure, tramp

for installing `tramp` of `emacs`, for `configure` operation, which prefix should I use? In the tramp's introduction.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-contrib
```

Comment: Unless your Emacs is really old, you don't need to install tramp: it is already part of Emacs. To get a newer Emacs than the one shipped by default, either use `homebrew`, `macports` or Aquamacs.

Comment: Thank you for your information. But if I want to use the latest tramp package, what prefix parameter should be used?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. What is important is that the installed files are in your `load-path` variable. To find out where your Emacs is installed use `which emacs`, this should give you a good idea for a canonical location.